# Controlling movement based on light.enabled. C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a mechanic in my new project where Enemies are programmed to chase the player but only if they have their "torch" enabled. As you will see in the script, I do this with a null check

Here is the code:

```
public class chasePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float speed;
    public Light playerLight;

    void followLight()
    {
        if (playerLight != null)
        {
            speed = 1;
            float walkspeed = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, walkspeed);
        }
    }

    void stopFollowing()
    {
        if (playerLight = null)
        {
            speed = 0;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        followLight();
        stopFollowing();
    }
}
```

The problem is, I think I have all the code right and in theory it should do what I want it to, but it doesnt. It doesn't move at all even when I start the game where it should.

What could I possibly be doing wrong.
First time doing an original script so probably lots going wrong

Comment: Any errors? Are you sure `playerLight` is not `null`? And in `stopFollowing()` is it a typo or do you really have `playerLight = null`? It should be `playerLight == null` .. otherwise you are setting your `playerLight` alsways to `null` and therefore it never moves

Comment: Thank you, that was an error but now even if moving at the start, the "enemy" does not stop moving when the light is turned off. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: Let's say the light is switched off. From your stopFollowing() method it seems to me that you expect your playerLight variable to be equal to null if it's switched off. So you set your speed variable to 0, all is good. However, the next time you go into your followLight() method, your light variable is still null. That means you will never enter the if-statement inside the followLight() method, and therefore never do a new speed calculation with the speed variable.

Comment: I understand what you mean, But I can't figure out a way to fix it. I turned all my lights to start as null with a void start() stopFollowing(); and changed the light to be off at the start in another script. However the enemy still chases me.

Comment: `if (playerLight = null)` should probably be `if (playerLight == null)` otherwise you're setting `playerLight` to null rather than testing if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veteran here! **laughs**

Before we start, I just want to mention that you are using C#, so try get used to `CamelCase` for naming methods and classes.

Your code is not working because you are checking your `Light` component for `null`. `null` is only going to be once nothing is assigned, or assigned object is destroyed. If you want to check the component's state, better use `playerLight.enabled`. Adding some minor improvements to your overall code and it now looks like:

```
public class ChasePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Light playerLight;
    public float speed;
    public Transform target;


    private void FollowLight()
    {
        // Does checking for given statement but is only executed in Debug mode.
        // Fairly good for fail-proofing private methods
        // Or clarifying, what values should be before invoking the method.
        Debug.Assert(playerLight != null);

        float walkspeed = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, walkspeed);      
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(playerLight != null && playerLight.enabled)
            FollowLight();
    }
}
```

***NOTE:*** don't forget to rename class file to `ChasePlayer` as I have CamelCased the class name (Unity requires that file and class names match in order to be able to assign components to GameObjects in the editor).

Comment: Funny how the only thing I needed was a couple lines and minor improvements to get this working. These are 2 hours of mistakes I won't make again and thats thanks to you. Your a great coder, enjoy your week :)

Comment: Thank you for the kind response. It really boosted my mood!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, try this:

```
public class chasePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float speed;
    public Light playerLight;

    void followLight()
    {
        if (playerLight != null)
        {
            speed = 1;
        }
        float walkspeed = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, walkspeed);            
    }

    void stopFollowing()
    {
        if (playerLight == null)
        {
            speed = 0;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        followLight();
        stopFollowing();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately this isn't working either. No matter what, I can't come up with a solution. I should probably wait for a veteran to help me with this. Thank you both so much for trying to help me :) If you can figure out a way to solve this problem though I will appreciate it greatly :))))